# How to use web.py module

Tags: python

Hi  i was writng simple web server...

here is code frament.

```
url = ('/comment','HandleComment','/question','HandleQuestion','/post','HandlePost')

class HandleAll:
      .
      .

webApi = web.application(urls, globals())
if __name__ == "__main__":
     webApi.run()
```

rather than using 3 diffrent class(HandleComment, HandleQuestion, HandlePost), i want to check which URL called in if statment

can any body help me..?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It defeats the purpose of using *web.py* a bit, but it is certainly possible to do it with one handler only:

```
import web

urls = ('/.*', 'Root')

class Root:
    def GET(self):
        url = web.url()
        if   url == '/comment':  pass
        elif url == '/question': pass
        elif url == '/post':     pass

    def POST(self):
        if web.url() == '/post':
            pass

app = web.application(urls, globals())
if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run()
```

If the class-per-handler syntax is not to your liking, perhaps you should give [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) a go.